# same statement different position lead to different result : local variable "os" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote codes to list all directories and files with  hierarchy in recursion way.There is a only one difference between code1 and code2, the position of "import os" .
CODE1 ：

```
def recur_dir(dn,level=0,result=[]):
    import os
    new_queue=[]
    if level==0:
        dn=[dn]
    for item in dn:
        result.append([level,item])
        if  os.path.isdir(item):
            for next_item in os.listdir(item):
                next_dn = os.path.join(item, next_item)
                new_queue.append(next_dn)
    level=level+1
    if len(dn)>0: recur_dir(new_queue,level,result)
    return result


>>> z=recur_dir("/home/jack",0,[])  
>>> z    
[[0, '/home/jack'], [1, '/home/jack/.ssh'], [1, '/home/jack/.profile'], [1, '/home/jack/.bashrc'], [1, '/home/jack/wp.sh'], [1, '/home/jack/.bash_history'], [1, '/home/jack/.bash_logout'], [2, '/home/jack/.ssh/known_hosts']]
```

I want to make 'import os' be called only one time in the running process, changed code1 into code2.

CODE2:

```
 def recur_dir(dn,level=0,result=[]):
    new_queue=[]
    if level==0:
        dn=[dn]
        import os
    for item in dn:
        result.append([level,item])
        if  os.path.isdir(item):
            for next_item in os.listdir(item):
                next_dn = os.path.join(item, next_item)
                new_queue.append(next_dn)
    level=level+1
    if len(dn)>0: recur_dir(new_queue,level,result)
    return result  


>>> y=recur_dir("/home/jack",0,[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 14, in recur_dir
File "<stdin>", line 9, in recur_dir
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
```

Please tell me the reason behind the code.

Comment: because `import os` is define inside of if loop

Comment: more details please?

Comment: Why not just put `import os` outside the function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This small experiment will answer your question:

```
In [2]: def recur_dir(level=0):
         if level==0:
                 import os
         elif level == 2:
                 return
         print globals().keys(), locals().keys()
         recur_dir(level+1)
   ...:         


In [3]: recur_dir(0)
['_dh', '__', 'help', 'quit', '__builtins__', 'recur_dir', '_ih', '__builtin__', '__name__', '___', '__package__', '_', '_sh', '_i3', '_i2', '_i1', '__doc__', '_iii', 'exit', 'get_ipython', '_i', 'In', '_ii', '_oh', 'Out'] 
['os', 'level']
    ['_dh', '__', 'help', 'quit', '__builtins__', 'recur_dir', '_ih', '__builtin__', '__name__', '___', '__package__', '_', '_sh', '_i3', '_i2', '_i1', '__doc__', '_iii', 'exit', 'get_ipython', '_i', 'In', '_ii', '_oh', 'Out'] 
['level']
```

As you may see, the imported *os* does not show in global scope - it is only added to the local scope. As you go on deeper with recursion, you create a new local scope - which does not contain *os*!

Answer (score 3):

Note that in the traceback error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/script.py", line 21, in <module>
    recur_dir('/tmp', 0, [])
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/script.py", line 18, in recur_dir
    if len(dn)>0: recur_dir(new_queue,level,result)   <- RECUR_DIR IS CALLED
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/script.py", line 13, in recur_dir
    if  os.path.isdir(item):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
```

the error does not occur until **after**

```
if len(dn)>0: recur_dir(new_queue,level,result)
```

is reached. In other words, the `UnboundLocalError` is being raised in the
*second* call to `recur_dir`, when `level` no longer equals zero.

Remember that by using `import os` inside `recur_dir`, `os` is defined as a *local variable*. It exists only within the function scope. When `recur_dir` is called recursively the second time, `os` is not defined. Hence the UnboundLocalError when `os` is encountered on line 13.

Answer (score 2):

because `import os` is define inside of `if` loop, so when `level` is `0` i.e `if level==0:` that time only `os` module is imported. When function is called with a `level` variable value is `not equal to 0` that time `if` condition is `False`, i.e. `import os` statement is not execute.

In first example:

`import os` is define at start of function i.e. every time when when is called `os` module is imported and we can access `os` in the function. Thats why code is working in first example.

---

Best way to define module at the start of py file.

OR

Define module at same level in function where function can access module at same level or nested level.

---

e.g:

```
>>> def test(no):
...   if no==0:
...      import os
...   print "I am os:", os
... 
>>> test(0)
I am os: <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> test(10)
I am os:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment
>>>
```